How to extract inline calculation when working with enumerables in Ruby?
I am trying to make a FizzBuzz in Ruby based on an enumerable. It works when I inline the calculation:
numb_array = (0..100)
numb_array.select { |numb| 
  if numb % 2 == 0 && numb % 3 == 0
    puts "fizzbuzz" 
  elsif numb % 2 == 0
    puts "buzz"
  elsif numb % 3 == 0
    puts "fizz"
  else 
    puts "none"
  end 
}

But trying to move the calculation outside the code block does not work, probably because I am trying to access numb as a global variable.
$div_1 = (numb % 2 == 0)
$div_2 = (numb % 3 == 0)

numb_array = (0..100)
numb_array.select {|numb| 
  if div_1 && div_2
    puts "fizzbuzz" 
  elsif div_1
    puts "fiz"
  elsif div_2
    puts "buzz"
  else 
    puts "none"
  end 
}

Can this even work?

I am not sure how using select makes sense here. Because select returns the values from the enumerable that match the condition. But you seem not to be interested in any values from the range, but instead you print strings depending on those values. each is the way to go in this example.

And regarding your second version. There is no global "numb object". numb % 2 == 0 expects the numb variable to be set, and that is only the case in the each block. In each iteration of the block, numb will be set to the current number from the numb_array. And because it is not set, your second version raises a undefined local variable or method 'numb' error.

It think what you are looking for is a lambda e.g. div_1 = ->(numb) {numb % 2 == 0} and div_2 = ->(numb) {numb % 3 == 0} then you could use if div_1[numb] && div_2[numb] etc.


Can this even work?

No, not like that. Even if numb were a global variable, div_1 and div_2 would be set only once. To get this working, you could move the calculation into a lambda / proc. This will defer the evaluation until you call the lambda(s): (passing numb)
div_1 = ->(n) { n % 2 == 0 }
div_2 = ->(n) { n % 3 == 0 }

numb_array.each do |numb|
  if div_1[numb] && div_2[numb]
    puts "fizzbuzz"
  elsif div_1[numb]
    puts "fiz"
  elsif div_2[numb]
    puts "buzz"
  else
    puts "none"
  end
end

However, be aware that both of div_1 and div_2 might be called (and thus evaluated) up to two times per iteration.
You could also just move the calculation right into the iteration and store it in a local variable, e.g.:
numb_array.each do |numb|
  div_1 = numb % 2 == 0
  div_2 = numb % 3 == 0

  if div_1 && div_2
    puts "fizzbuzz"
  elsif div_1
    puts "fiz"
  elsif div_2
    puts "buzz"
  else
    puts "none"
  end
end

Or you could map each value to a [div_1, div_2] pair prior to iteration. The pair can then be treated as if two values were yielded by each:
numb_array.map { |n| [n % 2 == 0, n % 3 == 0] }
          .each do |div_1, div_2|
  if div_1 && div_2
    puts "fizzbuzz"
  elsif div_1
    puts "fiz"
  elsif div_2
    puts "buzz"
  else
    puts "none"
  end
end

Or maybe utilize Ruby's pattern matching:
numb_array.each do |n|
  case [n % 2, n % 3]
  in [0, 0]
    puts "fizzbuzz"
  in [0, *]
    puts "fiz"
  in [*, 0]
    puts "buzz"
  else
    puts "none"
  end
end

I've replaced select with each in the above examples, because you're merely traversing the array, not actually selecting anything from it.
